# Is there a way to convert .ev3 files to .uf2 files?

Tags: ev3, technic, robotic, education

I am using Lego Mindstorms EV3 Education Edition and I am wondering if there is a way to convert the default `.ev3` files to `.uf2` files

Comment: Hello, and Welcome, please tell us what program/s opens uf2 files, or specifically, the program you plan to use.

Comment: I have found references to a specific microcontroller firmware type: https://github.com/Microsoft/uf2 and https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-feather-m0-express-designed-for-circuit-python-circuitpython/uf2-bootloader-details Is this what you mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.UF2` file format [appears to be](https://github.com/Microsoft/uf2) a fairly compact, binary format for reliably transferring data to "microcontrollers" (i.e. small embedded systems such as the EV3 controller), and is the format used by the [Microsoft MakeCode application](https://makecode.mindstorms.com/), recommended as part of the First LEGO League.

The `.ev3` file is [actually a zip file](http://attila.farago.hu.gitlab.io/EV3TreeVisualizerPages/filesyntax.html) containing a number of additional files, of which the `.ev3p` is an XML file representing the program itself.

At this time there isn't an official way to convert `.ev3` programs to the `.uf2` format, not least because things like [custom blocks](https://makecode.mindstorms.com/blocks/custom) will need to be re-written in JavaScript, and certain other features may not be currently supported (i.e. data logging beyond console logging, 3rd party sensors, etc.).

Comment: Thx :) Keep Up The Good Work!!!

Comment: The new Scratch-based software compiles to .rbf like the old desktop software, not .uf2.